# Integral operator $\frac{g(s)}{1+(\cdot-s)^2}$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: operator-theory

Show that

$(Ag)(t)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{g(s)}{1+(s-t)^2}ds, \ \ g \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$,

defines a bounded, self adjoint operator that is not compact.

Got the first part. As for the second part I want to apply Fubini's theorem but lacking a motivation to do so. Also like some on the compactness part if not shown to a suitable example.

Comment: Your operator is a convolution with $t\mapsto \frac 1 {1+t^2}$. So in the Fourier domain, it's simply a pointwise multiplication with the Fourier transform of that function, which is known, something like $\xi\mapsto e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$.

Comment: So as for the self-adjoint part, you're telling me to use Plancharel. Thanks.

Other approaches and pointers on the third, someone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be the Fourier transform operator, defined on $L^2(\mathbb R)$as
$$Fg(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb R} g(s)e^{-2i\pi \xi s}ds$$
Then $F$ is an isometry (by Plancherel/Parseval), which means that $F^{-1}=F^*$.

Note that $A$ is a convolution operator:
$$Af = g \circledast h $$
where $$h(s)=\frac 1 {1+s^2}$$
The Fourier transform of that function is well-known (you can verify it by using the inverse Fourier transform formula):
$$Fh(\xi)=\hat h(\xi)=\pi e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$$
Because the Fourier transform maps convolutions to pointwise products, it follows that:
$$(FAg)(\xi)=F(h \circledast g)(\xi)=(Fh)(\xi).(Fg)(\xi)=\hat h(\xi).(Fg)(\xi)$$
In other words, for any $u\in L^2(\mathbb R)$:
$$(FAF^{-1})u = (FAF^*)u = \hat h. u\tag{1}$$
Thus, this tells us everything we need to know about $A$ itself.

**A is bounded**

$F$ being an isometry, it suffices to verify that $FAF^{-1}$ is bounded, and that follows from
$$\|FAF^{-1}u\|^2=\int_{\mathbb R}|\hat h(\xi)u(\xi)|^2 d\xi\leq \pi^2\|u\|^2$$

**A is self-adjoint**

Again, by $(1)$, it suffices to verify that the pointwise multiplication operator is self-adjoint. For $u$ and $v$ in $L^2(\mathbb R)$,
$$\int_{\mathbb R} \overline{v(\xi)}\left(\hat h(\xi)u(\xi)\right)d\xi = 2\pi\int_{\mathbb R} \overline{v(\xi)}u(\xi)e^{-2\pi|xi|}d\xi = \overline{\int_{\mathbb R} \overline{u(\xi)}\left(\hat h(\xi)v(\xi)\right)d\xi}$$

**A is not compact**

If it were, then so would the pointwise multiplication operator $FAF^{-1}=FAF^*$, since $F$ is an isometry. We also know that self-adjoint compact operators have a countable set of eigenvalues. Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue with eigenfunction $u$. Then for almost all $\xi\in\mathbb R$,
$$\hat h(\xi)u(\xi)=\pi e^{-2\pi |\xi|} u(\xi) = \lambda u(\xi)$$
Because the set of values of $\xi$ for which $u(\xi)\neq 0$ is of positive measure, this implies that $\lambda = 2\pi e^{-2\pi|\xi|}$ for that set of $\xi$, which is impossible.

**Generalization to all convolution operators**

There's nothing special about function $h$. The steps above can be repeated for any function $h$, and we conclude that all convolution operators (for the Lebesgue measure) are bounded, self-adjoint and non-compact.

Comment: I raise my hat. So with the Fourier Transform being unitary as you say, I should think of the operator A as being diagonalized and unitarily equivalent to multiplication by h hat? And should I consider your account as an archetype among such?

Comment: That's correct!